# jquery asp.net hover box for multiple divs created in code behind into a literal control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to draw a map and I have a List of a village object. And I work out the view window of the map then loop through each co-ordinate checking to see if a village exists there from a database. If one does, I draw the village. What I really would like is to be able to to have a jquery hover menu when hovering over each village.

At the moment I have it so when you hover over a village, all the hover menus show for every village, because of course they all share the same image id and hover menu ids. But if I change them to be unique ids, how can I make the hover boxes for every village?

This is my code at the moment (I'm looping through and writing to a literal control)

Map.aspx.cs

```
MapLiteral.Text = "";
    MapLiteral.Text += "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";

    for (int i = minx; i <= maxx; i++)
    {
        MapLiteral.Text += "<tr>";
        for (int j = miny; j <= maxy; j++)
        {
            MapLiteral.Text += "<td width\"50px\" height=\"50px\" style=\"border: solid 1px #2d5c25;\">";
            if (Objects.Village.VillageExists(i, j))
            {
                Objects.Village village = new Objects.Village();
                village = Objects.Village.GetVillage(i, j);
                MapLiteral.Text += "<div class=\"village\"><img src=\"/Images/Map/Village1.gif\" /></div>";
                MapLiteral.Text += "<div class=\"villagehover\" id=\"villagehover\">test</div>";
            }
            else
            {
                MapLiteral.Text += "<img src=\"/Images/Map/Grass.gif\" />";
            }
            MapLiteral.Text += "</td>";
        }
        MapLiteral.Text += "</tr>";
    }

    MapLiteral.Text += "</table>";
```

Map.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".villagehover").hide()
        $(".village").hover(
  function () {
      $('.villagehover').stop().fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
  },
  function () {
      $('.villagehover').stop().fadeOut("slow");
  }
);

    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<center>
    <h2>
        Map (<asp:Label ID="XTitleLabel" runat="server" />,
        <asp:Label ID="YTitleLabel" runat="server" />)
    </h2>
     <asp:Literal ID="MapLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with a better selector. As you are seeing, `$('.villagehover')` is selecting all of the hover divs. In jQuery, `this` is set to the selected element (within the hover function), so you can get the correct hover div by using

```
$(this).parent().find('.villagehover')
```

Also remember that you can only have one `id="villagehover"` per page.